# How to install ace stream on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ace

**How can I install Ace Stream Media on Ubuntu 15.04?**
I tried it using the repository key for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times to install acestream on lubuntu and ubuntu that I almost gave up.

Actually it seems that there are no more official repo for acestream.

So, what I did is to install Acestream with Wine.

To install Wine, enter the following commands in your terminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.8
```

Or find more information there: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu in order to install Wine

Then, find "Configure Wine" (probably in your "Start Menu") and find the tab "Applications" and change "Windows version" to "Windows XP".

Then browse your C: drive (shortcut is the Start Menu or browse `/home/YOURNICKNAME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/` If you don't see the folder `/.wine/` try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to see hidden folders) and copy/paste the Windows installer you downloaded from http://wiki.acestream.org/wiki/index.php/AceStream_3.0/en

Then install the software.

The software is supposed to be installed in `/home/YOURNICKNAME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/YOURNICKNAME/Application Data/ACEStream/player`

So just launch the file ace_player.exe to launch it. Maybe it is already launched in background. So close it and re-launch it.

After make a shortcut of the folder to your desktop. So go back to `/home/YOURNICKNAME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/YOURNICKNAME/Application Data/ACEStream/` and select the folder `/player/`. Then click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and move the folder to your desktop to make it a shortcut.

And then it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Kodi, then add plexus addon. That will allow you to play acestreams. Thats what I am using.

Comment: Hi, could you offer a link or directions on how to make the acestream run? I've installed both, but in Plexus, my acestream won't accept CTRL+V as paste and even if I type the long acestream:// code, it won't play. Using Ubuntu 16.04. But everything's installed.

Comment: Yes that is a pain. I generally use android remote for kodi to copy and paste the acestream url and it always have worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

hmmm did you try this?

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/acestream.list 
$sudo wget -O – http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add –
$sudo apt-get update

Edit

if that dosent work go here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2xofe4Yj9veDMwUlFXN2w1akE/edit?usp=sharing
the above contains all the needed dependencies and should work the same for 15.04 but I could be wrong
and use this code
$sudo dpkg -i acestream-engine-fix-Ubuntu_14.04.deb

Edit
I just double checked a website and it says its not out yet for 14.04 and 15.04

Comment: if you are trying to steam games or other things open broadcaster works just fine on linux now :)

Comment: doesn't work
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: yeah I know tis why I made an edit about how i double checked on the website your ubuntu version is not compatible with that software you will just have to use open braodcaster